# PHP Accessing Database through Text Box

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I am having a problem with some PHP code that accesses a database. When I attempt to preview the page with the scripts, I am getting the error "Unable to select database". The purpose of this code is to access a prayer database that (with this portion of the code) enables you to edit prayer requests as they are sent in. The code is in two different CGI files. They can be found below.

First CGI File: ApproveDenyPrayerRequest

```
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>Prayer Request</td>
</tr>

<?php

$username="fbc";
$password="xxxxxxxx";
$database="prayer";

mysql_connect('fbcaltusprayerorg'.ipagemysql.com,$username,$password.prayer);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM Request";
$result=mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo ("<tr><td>$row[Reg_F_Name]</td>");
echo ("<td>$row[Reg_L_Name]</td>");
echo ("<td>$row[Reg_Request]</td>");
echo ("<td><a href=\"cgi-bin/PrayerRequest.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Second CGI File: PrayerRequest

```
<?php

$username="fbc";
$password="xxxxxxxx";
$database="prayer";

mysql_connect('fbcaltusprayerorg.ipagemysql.com',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Request"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form method="post" action="cgi-bin/ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php" />

<table>

<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="first" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_F_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="last" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_L_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Prayer Request</td>
<td><input type="text" name="request" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_Request]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Thanks all for your responses.

Comment: First, you should use mysqli_ instead of mysql_ functions.  Next, is the database located on the same server as the PHP?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks for your response. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it still says "Unable to select database". I made the changes from mysql to mysqli as well as the changes suggested by jeroen. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo with the quote and a misformed string concatenation at the end:

```
mysql_connect('fbcaltusprayerorg'.ipagemysql.com,$username,$password.prayer);
```

Should probably be:

```
mysql_connect('fbcaltusprayerorg.ipagemysql.com',$username,$password);
```

And you should switch to PDO or mysqli as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

And if you posted your real password, you should change it right away.

Comment: That was not my password hahahaha! Good catch though. I will try what you suggested and let you know. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it still says "Unable to select database". I made the changes from mysql to mysqli as well as the changes you suggested jeroen. Any other suggestions?